# Programmatically use UIStackView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uistackview

I'm trying to create this UI:

[image]

Using this code:

```
extension String {

  func style(_ attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]) -> NSAttributedString {

    return NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: attributes)
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private weak var newContainer: UIView?
  private weak var newScrollContainer: UIScrollView?
  private weak var newInputContainer: UIStackView?

  private func addNewContainer() {

    let container = UIView()
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newContainer = container

    view.addSubview(container)
    container.topAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
      constant: 0).isActive = true
    container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 368).isActive = true
  }

  private func configureNewContainer() {

    newContainer?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 188/255, blue: 188/255, alpha: 1)
    newContainer?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    newContainer?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    newContainer?.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    newContainer?.layer.maskedCorners = [
      .layerMaxXMaxYCorner,
      .layerMaxXMinYCorner,
      .layerMinXMaxYCorner,
      .layerMinXMinYCorner]
  }

  private func addNewScrollContainer() {

    guard let container = newContainer else { return }
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.newScrollContainer = scroll

    newContainer?.addSubview(scroll)
    scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
    scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 28).isActive = true
    scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: container.trailingAnchor,
      constant: 18).isActive = true
    scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: 36).isActive = true
  }

  private func addStack() {

    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    self.newInputContainer = stack

    newScrollContainer?.addSubview(stack)
    newScrollContainer?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    newScrollContainer?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    newScrollContainer?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
    newScrollContainer?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  }

  private func addStackControls() {

    guard let container = newInputContainer else { return }

    let red: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

    let dest = UITextField()
    dest.attributedPlaceholder = "destination".style(red)

    let cost = UITextField()
    cost.attributedPlaceholder = "cost".style(red)

    let pets = UITextField()
    pets.attributedPlaceholder = "pets".style(red)

    let people = UITextField()
    people.attributedPlaceholder = "people".style(red)

    let horizDivider = UIView()
    horizDivider.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    horizDivider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    let width = container.frame.size.width*0.85
    horizDivider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true

    let origin = UITextField()
    origin.attributedPlaceholder = "origin".style(red)

    let departure = UITextField()
    departure.attributedPlaceholder = "departure".style(red)

    let note = UITextField()
    note.attributedPlaceholder = "note".style(red)

    let help = UIButton()
    help.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26).isActive = true
    help.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26).isActive = true
    help.layer.cornerRadius = 13
    help.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
    help.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    help.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    help.layer.borderWidth = 1

    help.setAttributedTitle("?".style([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]), for: .normal)

    let vertDivider = UIView()
    vertDivider.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    vertDivider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    vertDivider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    let save = UIButton()
    save.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    save.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91).isActive = true
    save.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    save.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
    save.layer.borderWidth = 1
    save.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    save.backgroundColor = .clear

    let costPetsPeople = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [cost, pets, people])
    costPetsPeople.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
    costPetsPeople.distribution = .fillEqually
    costPetsPeople.axis = .horizontal

    let originDeparture = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [origin, departure])
    originDeparture.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
    originDeparture.distribution = .fillEqually
    costPetsPeople.axis = .horizontal

    let helpDividerSave = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [help, vertDivider, save])
    helpDividerSave.distribution = .fillProportionally
    helpDividerSave.axis = .horizontal

    [dest, costPetsPeople, horizDivider, originDeparture, note, helpDividerSave].forEach {

      newInputContainer?.addArrangedSubview($0)
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    addNewContainer()
    configureNewContainer()
    addNewScrollContainer()
    addStack()
    addStackControls()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 206/255, green: 196/255, blue: 163/255, alpha: 1)
  }
}
```

but I get this:

[image]

This is the view hierarchy:
[image]

Thank you for reading, I hope you can help :).

Comment: You have conflicts , read them to fix the problem

Comment: @Sh_Khan - I only have conflicts when I add things to the stack view, which I thought was supposed to eliminate the need for constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Couple notes...

1. Use `guard` to unwrap objects to avoid things like: `newContainer?.layer.borderWidth = 1`
2. Start with one element at a time... if you cannot see your "destination" textField, you probably won't see anything else either. As you add each additional element, it will be easy to see when something gets thrown off.
3. Use "batch" constraint additions, and group them logically. Just makes it easier to read and track what's going on.
4. Give views contrasting background colors to make it easier to see where the frames are going.

Here is your modified code... you'll still have a few things to tweak to get exactly what you want, but this should get you on your way (lots of comments to help you see what I did):

```
extension String {

    func style(_ attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]) -> NSAttributedString {

        return NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: attributes)
    }
}

class PanelViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var newContainerView: UIView?
    private weak var newScrollView: UIScrollView?
    private weak var newInputStackView: UIStackView?

    private func addNewContainer() {

        let container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        newContainerView = container

        view.addSubview(container)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 368),
            ])

    }

    private func configureNewContainer() {

        guard let container = newContainerView else { return }

        container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 188/255, blue: 188/255, alpha: 1)
        container.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        container.layer.borderWidth = 1
        container.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        container.layer.maskedCorners = [
            .layerMaxXMaxYCorner,
            .layerMaxXMinYCorner,
            .layerMinXMaxYCorner,
            .layerMinXMinYCorner]
    }

    private func addNewScrollContainer() {

        guard let container = newContainerView else { return }

        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.newScrollView = scroll

        container.addSubview(scroll)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: 75),
            scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 28),
            scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -18),
            scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: -36),
            ])

    }

    private func addStack() {

        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
        stack.distribution = .fill
        self.newInputStackView = stack

        guard let nsc = newScrollView else { return }
        nsc.addSubview(stack)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nsc.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nsc.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nsc.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nsc.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

    }

    private func addStackControls() {

        // unwrap here to avoid the need for "?"
        guard let inputStackView = newInputStackView,
            let theScrollView = newScrollView
                else { return }

        let red: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

        let dest = UITextField()
        dest.attributedPlaceholder = "destination".style(red)

        let cost = UITextField()
        cost.attributedPlaceholder = "cost".style(red)

        let pets = UITextField()
        pets.attributedPlaceholder = "pets".style(red)

        let people = UITextField()
        people.attributedPlaceholder = "people".style(red)

        let horizDivider = UIView()
        horizDivider.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        // to get the horizDivider centered we need to embed it
        // in a "containing" view
        let horizDividerContainingView = UIView()
        horizDividerContainingView.addSubview(horizDivider)

        let origin = UITextField()
        origin.attributedPlaceholder = "origin".style(red)

        let departure = UITextField()
        departure.attributedPlaceholder = "departure".style(red)

        let note = UITextField()
        note.attributedPlaceholder = "note".style(red)

        let help = UIButton()
        help.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        help.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        help.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        help.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        help.layer.borderWidth = 1

        help.setAttributedTitle("?".style([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]), for: .normal)

        let vertDivider = UIView()
        vertDivider.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        let save = UIButton()
        save.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        save.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        save.layer.borderWidth = 1
        save.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        save.backgroundColor = .clear

        save.setTitle("save", for: .normal)

        // horizontal stack view for cost / pets / people fields
        let costPetsPeople = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [cost, pets, people])
        costPetsPeople.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
        costPetsPeople.distribution = .fillEqually
        costPetsPeople.axis = .horizontal

        // horizontal stack view for origin / departure fields
        let originDeparture = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [origin, departure])
        originDeparture.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
        originDeparture.distribution = .fillEqually
        costPetsPeople.axis = .horizontal

        // horizontal stack view for help / save buttons fields
        let helpDividerSave = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [help, vertDivider, save])
        helpDividerSave.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
        helpDividerSave.distribution = .fill
        helpDividerSave.axis = .horizontal

        // to get the buttons stack view "right-aligned" we need to embed it
        // in a "containing" view
        let helpDividerSaveContainingView = UIView()
        helpDividerSaveContainingView.addSubview(helpDividerSave)

        // add elements to the vertical "input" stack view
        [dest, costPetsPeople, horizDividerContainingView, originDeparture, note, helpDividerSaveContainingView].forEach {
            inputStackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }

        // make sure everything has translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [dest, cost, pets, people, horizDivider, horizDividerContainingView,
         origin, departure, note, help, vertDivider, save,
         costPetsPeople, originDeparture, helpDividerSave, helpDividerSaveContainingView,
         ].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // set all the textField backgrounds to white
        [dest, cost, pets, people, origin, departure, note].forEach {
            $0.backgroundColor = .white
        }

        // setup all the elements' constraints here
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // we want the vertical "input" stack view to take up the full width
            // of the scroll view
            inputStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // horizontal divider 1-pt height, 85% width, centered in its containing view
            horizDivider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
            horizDivider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizDividerContainingView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.85),
            horizDivider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizDividerContainingView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // help button 26 x 26 pts
            help.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26),
            help.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26),

            // save button 91-pts wide
            save.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 91),

            // vertical divider 1-pt width
            vertDivider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),

            // buttons stack view constrained "right-aligned" to its containing view
            helpDividerSave.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helpDividerSaveContainingView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            helpDividerSave.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helpDividerSaveContainingView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            helpDividerSave.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: helpDividerSaveContainingView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            ])

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        addNewContainer()
        configureNewContainer()
        addNewScrollContainer()
        addStack()
        addStackControls()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 206/255, green: 196/255, blue: 163/255, alpha: 1)

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]